# How to open a program by bash script direct on a workspace which is not the most active workspace

Tags: linux, bash

How to open a program by bash direct on a workspace = virtual desktop, which is specified by number.

## Environment:

```
Linux Mint, Cinnamon desktop manager
bash
Program which should be open by bash script on a virtual desktop, which is specified by number: editor xed
```

Problem: A new program will be normally open by bash script on currently active and or maybe on the workspace on which the bash script is running.

## What's known:

How to get the number of workspace on which the Script is working:

```
nr_of_active_desktop=activedesktop=$(wmctrl -d | grep "*" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1)
echo $nr_of_active_desktop
```

How to open xed by bash on foreground of most active workspace and move it to by number spicified workspace:

```
Sample for: Open a the program xed on one workspace on foreground and move it after than to one other workspace.

open_on_workspace_nr=1
move_to_workspace_nr=2

wmctrl -s $move_to_workspace_nr
xed & sleep 3; wmctrl -s $open_on_workspace_nr
```

## What's unknown:

- How to start xed direct on a specific virtual desktop. Thats mean without to open it on currend active workspace and move it to the workspace which is given by a var
- If this isnt possible, open xed in the backbround of most active workspace and move it to the workspace which is specified by number, without to change the most active workspace to this one, on which the xed will moved.

Comment: What is a "workspace"?

Comment: Workspace = Desktop

Comment: @KamilCuk : From my understanding, it is quite common in the LinuxMint community to refer to a virtual desktop (at least under Cinnamon) as a _workspace_.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, sorry, I just didn't know OP was referring to _that_ "workspace".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Window manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Window_manager) is an application that chooses where to place new windows. If you want to start an application at a specific position, configure your window manager to do that. Some window managers offer *extensive* configuration options. There are also applications that like listen/poll for new application windows within a window manager and execute actions then (I am thinking of devilspie-like programs here).

Overall, if you **want** to do it in bash, the only thing you can do is to start the program and have it anywhere, and then write a short script that would move the window, basically:

```
id=$(wait_for_my_window "xed")
move_window_to_desktop "$id"
```

And implement the waiting and moving using `wmctrl` and `xdotool` utilities with some scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This script (test.sh) should achieve what you expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function search_xid_by_class {
    xdotool search --class $1|sort -n
}

function start_xprog_and_move_to_desktop {
    local class=$1 target_desktop=$2 existing_xids new_xids xids; shift 2
    local current_desktop=$(xdotool get_desktop)
    existing_xids="$(search_xid_by_class $class)"
    "$@" & # Start x program in active desktop
    for ((c=SECONDS+2; c > SECONDS;)) do
        new_xids="$(search_xid_by_class $class)"
        xids+=($(comm -13 <(echo "$existing_xids") <(echo "$new_xids")))
        existing_xids="$new_xids"
        sleep .1
    done
    # Move last xid to the target_desktop
    test -n "$xids" && xdotool set_desktop_for_window ${xids[-1]} $target_desktop
}

start_xprog_and_move_to_desktop "$@"
```

Calling method :

```
bash test.sh xed 1 xed
```

First `xed` is the class name of `xed`. If it's not `xed`, you can find it with `xprop`.

`1` is the target desktop number (0-based)

Second `xed` is the command to run.

Comment: Pls add to describtion, your solution open xed directly on wanted workspace or open on most active one in background and mouve than the opened xed to the wanted workspace.

Comment: I tested it now. Its open the xed on most active desktop on foreground and dont move the xed to a othe desktop. It can be a more clasasical solution like a bash file which start with #!/bin/bash and using p.e. a clasiscal function will be more easy to use on different systems. The solution give also a error message in a loop like "return: »Return« is only possible to run from inside a function or one with »source« running script.

Comment: My last update should start `xed` on most active one in background and mouve than the opened xed to the wanted workspace.

Comment: I have seen the answer now.

Comment: I don't remember on this moment.